# Share Url from browser to React Native app

Tags: react-native

I want to share URLs from the browser to my React Native app and open them in the app, how can I do that?

Comment: I think you may be able to use this or any similar repo to add this feature for your app: https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension

Answer (score 0):

This is called deep-linking, that your app launches and even does some actions depending on the called URL of your app. Many apps use it that's how you probably know it.

You can read about this and implement it.

Here is some articles and documentation about it:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/

https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e